# multiple search in dbf

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

When entering data in a text box, you must search by name, identify, address and telephone when clicking on the search button, but sometimes the search does not work well.

this is the button code:

```
SELECT clientes2

IF !EMPTY(THISFORM.Text1.Value)
GO TOP
SET ORDER TO
SET ORDER TO nombre
SEEK ALLTRIM(thisform.text1.Value)
thisform.Refresh
ENDIF


IF !EMPTY(THISFORM.Text1.Value)
GO TOP
SET ORDER TO
SET ORDER TO identifica
SEEK ALLTRIM(thisform.text1.Value)
thisform.Refresh
ENDIF

IF !EMPTY(THISFORM.Text1.Value)
GO TOP
SET ORDER TO
SET ORDER TO direccion
SEEK ALLTRIM(thisform.text1.Value)
thisform.Refresh
ENDIF

IF !EMPTY(THISFORM.Text1.Value)
GO TOP
SET ORDER TO
SET ORDER TO telefono
SEEK ALLTRIM(thisform.text1.Value)
thisform.Refresh
ENDIF
```

Comment: Asking the same question with a different name doesn't change the result. Check the comment written for the same question where you used Ives as name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158780/multiple-search-in-a-datagrid

Comment: IOW, your code fails because it does look in one column after the other but then continues without caring for the result of the previous step, so at the end it only the last result persists if any. Same for your questions, you do not seem to read the responses :)

Comment: Probably you may rather want to do a `Select ... From yourTable where col1 Like '%yourValue%' Or col2 Like '%yourValue% etc....` Or do a `Set Filter To (yourExpression)` which would be a worse performance than SQL